# The entry source (Data Extension) filter doesn't work properly

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have a Journey with a Data Extension as an Entry Source. This Data Extension is connected to Contact Data in order to use it to filter the contacts who access to the Journey. The filter is the following:

- **ProductGroup** equal Executive Masters and **StageName** equal Engaged

My issue is that when I test the Journey I obtain the following result:

Contact Didn't Enter Journey

> The entry source filter prevented the contact from entering.

I don't understand the result because the contact I'm testing fulfills the filter conditions (see the following image). What might I have done wrong? How can I fix it?

[image: Contact Didn't Enter Journey]

Comment: Can you comment on whether this just started happening?  First thing I'm trying to deduce if it is release related.

Comment: Also, is your Data Extension Sendable?

Comment: do you have a 1:N situation? if there are multiple records in the de for a subscriber and ones doesn't meet criteria could cause the issue

Comment: Hi Timothy,
Yes my data extension is sendable and it happens when the journey starts, the population within the data extension aren't injected to the journey although their information fulfills the filter conditions.
Thank you,

Comment: Hi EazyE, 

Yes I have a 1:N Situation...but your answer have helped me to realize that I had selected wrong the field as subscriber ID, after change it I have solve my issue :)
Thanks for your help!